# Had to switch my computer from RAID to AHCI -- should I be concerned?

Tags: boot, raid, data-corruption, ahci

I'm a bit of a noob so sorry if this is a bad question. I recently accidentally spilled some liquid on my Dell laptop which I bought years ago with ubuntu 18.04 pre-installed. Fortunately, the repair people were able to clean it and it seems to be working normally with one caveat -- when they first tried to boot it, it would only boot to an initramfs prompt and complain of "waiting for root device" and "UUID=xxxx does not exist!" or something like that. After a bit of googling, I found that I could seemingly fix this issue just by switching the SATA operations from RAID to AHCI in the BIOS, after which it looks like it boots and functions normally. My question is just this -- given that this happened after a spill, should I be concerned that there is some kind of corruption to the file system lurking somewhere that may cause problems down the line? I don't even know if the system was in RAID or AHCI mode before this all happened so I'm not sure what would be considered normal. Thanks for your consideration!

Comment: Given the hardware (the spill) nature of your problem, I don't think you will find any answer here. My advice is make two or three backup copies of your valuable data (that means documents, photos, music, etc.) into two or three external drives. If the spill changed the UEFI setting from AHCI to RAID who knows what else is affected by the spill.

Comment: RAID implies multiple HHDs which is quite rare on a laptop. Also, if RAID it was, and you switch from RAID to AHCI, it won't boot.

Comment: @mikewhatever thanks, this is reassuring! though it is worrisome that the setting somehow got switched. I think maybe this had more to do with the computer not shutting down properly than the liquid damage itself though. Fingers crossed.

Comment: Did the repair folks update UEFI. That would reset it to defaults which would probably have turned RAID back on. Most older Dells have required RAID or Intel RST changed to AHCI. Very new systems using NVMe drives just work as Linux has vmd driver. Lots of technical info, but says no real performance difference with RAID vs AHCI. https://www.dell.com/community/Laptops-General-Read-Only/Dell-M-2-FAQ-regarding-AHCI-vs-RAID-ON-Storage-Drivers-M-2-Lanes/td-p/5072571

Comment: @oldfred I'm not sure but it's possible. At any rate it sounds like there isn't much use worrying for the time being and I'll just have to hope the system & important data are usable.

Comment: Indeed, but you should have backups anyway, always.